# Using a string as variable name

Tags: stata

I have a dataset like this:

```
string_var | var1 | var2 | var3
var2       |  8   |   8  |  4
var3       |  7   |   5  |  7        
var2       |  10  |   10 |  5
```

I need to test whether `var1` is equal to *either* `var2` *or* `var3`, depending on the string that is contained in `string_var`. My problem is to convert these strings into variable names to do something like:

```
gen test=1 if var1==string_var
```

where, after the `==`, I need some kind of conversion function to let Stata read the string e.g. `var2` as the following:

```
gen test=1 if var1==var2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With just two possibilities, you can branch on the choice. (With several possibilities, I think you'd need a loop.)

```
clear 
input str4 string_var  var1  var2  var3
var2         8      8    4
var3         7      5    7        
var2         10     10   5
end 

gen test = cond(string_var == "var2", var1 == var2, var1 == var3) 

list 

     +--------------------------------------+
     | string~r   var1   var2   var3   test |
     |--------------------------------------|
  1. |     var2      8      8      4      1 |
  2. |     var3      7      5      7      1 |
  3. |     var2     10     10      5      1 |
     +--------------------------------------+
```

EDIT:

Here is a more general solution. (If anyone else thinks of a neater solution, be sure to post.)

```
gen test = . 

levelsof string_var, local(names) 

quietly foreach name of local names { 
    replace test = var1 == `name' if string_var == "`name'" 
}
```

Comment: Yes I do have more then two choices, how would this translate into a loop?

Comment: It works perfectly. I must admit I had never seen this replacing a variable directly with a tested condition. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I haven't often seen this except in the context of row-wise operations in which people want e.g. the name of whichever variable contains the maximum (itself problematic whenever there are ties).